# "Row larger than the maximum allowed size"

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to import some json.gz data into BigQuery.
I have 20 datasets (one per year).
The import processes chokes on 5 of them with the "Row larger than the maximum allowed size" error message.

What does that mean?
Is there a way to expand the size?
Is there a way to have the importer ignore the error?

regards,

Arnaud

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size of a row is 20 MB. If you set the maxBadRecords value in the [load configuration](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#importing), it will allow that many failed records in the load job.